# Retrieve html from website

Tags: c#, visual-studio, html-parsing

This is a little bit tricky but this is how it goes.

1. Page loads
2. Executes some javascript which generates more html code. And source code is the one I need.
   Now I see I can't use html parser because there isn't actually a way to run the code.
   Using http I can manage getting the first source code but the javascript isn't executed so I never get the source code I need.

What is the best way to retrieve that code generated afterwards?

Edit: I am trying to avoid using a hidden web browser. It is actually possible with it since it works as a javascript interpreter here but it is very slow and very ugly way.

Edit2: Added code

```
static private string _InetReadEx(string sUrl)
        {
            string aRet;
            HttpWebRequest webReq = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(sUrl);
            try
            {
                webReq.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
                webReq.Method = "GET";
                using (WebResponse response = webReq.GetResponse())
                {
                    using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
                    {
                        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
                        aRet = reader.ReadToEnd();
                        return aRet;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return string.Empty;
            }
        }
```

Comment: If you're generating the HTML, then you have the HTML.

Comment: are you trying to download the html source from a give and or specific webpage..? if so please show your code also this can easily be done using WebClient. perhaps you can show us what you have so far so we won't all be confused and or play the guessing game

Comment: @MethodMan I am trying to get the html of a specific webpage. Code added

Comment: then take a look at this http://webkitdotnet.sourceforge.net/ and if that doesn't work then do some googling there are lots of topics on this all over the web

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're using **WebBrowser** as you mentioned you want to avoid. There is no other conveneiet way.

You can mimic the behavior of the JavaScript that runs and execute it and than format it as the **WebBrowser** does, but this will not be dynamic formatting and thus much less desired.

Comment: I will use this on both a desktop and phone app. It will be very slow process on the phone application.

Comment: hmmm. I used webbrowser but I got an issue. The server tells me that my browser is outdated. It is a WP8.1 application. So this wouldn't work neither

Comment: So what about the second way? Can you lend me a hand there? I am not sure how to do that